# jQuery Dialog Box not working with Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, dialog

I am trying to open jquery dialogue box but its not opening i am also using jquery datepicker. when i remove two jquery script for date picker, dialogue opens otherwise its not working in any way. Anybody suggest me any jquery scripts for dialogue box that can work with these datepicker script.

javascript datepicker code:

```
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>/*
window.onerror = function(errorMsg) {
    $('#console').html($('#console').html()+'<br>'+errorMsg)
}*/
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
dayOfWeekStart : 1,
lang:'en',
disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
startDate:  '1986/01/05'
});
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'2015/04/15 05:03',step:10});

$('.some_class').datetimepicker();

$('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    formatTime:'H:i',
    formatDate:'d.m.Y',
    //defaultDate:'8.12.1986', // it's my birthday
    defaultDate:'+03.01.1970', // it's my birthday
    defaultTime:'10:00',
    timepickerScrollbar:false
});

$('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
    step:5,
    inline:true
});
$('.datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
    mask:'9999/19/39 29:59'
});

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'H:i',
    step:5
});
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    yearOffset:222,
    lang:'ch',
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/Y',
    formatDate:'Y/m/d',
    minDate:'-1970/01/02', // yesterday is minimum date
    maxDate:'+1970/01/02' // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
});
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    inline:true
});
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
$('#open').click(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker('show');
});
$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker('hide');
});
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker('reset');
});
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    allowTimes:['12:00','13:00','15:00','17:00','17:05','17:20','19:00','20:00'],
    step:5
});
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
$('#destroy').click(function(){
    if( $('#datetimepicker6').data('xdsoft_datetimepicker') ){
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker('destroy');
        this.value = 'create';
    }else{
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        this.value = 'destroy';
    }
});
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
    if (currentDateTime && currentDateTime.getDay() == 6){
        this.setOptions({
            minTime:'11:00'
        });
    }else
        this.setOptions({
            minTime:'8:00'
        });
};
$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    onChangeDateTime:logic,
    onShow:logic
});
$('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({
    onGenerate:function( ct ){
        $(this).find('.xdsoft_date')
            .toggleClass('xdsoft_disabled');
    },
    minDate:'-1970/01/2',
    maxDate:'+1970/01/2',
    timepicker:false
});
$('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
    onGenerate:function( ct ){
        $(this).find('.xdsoft_date.xdsoft_weekend')
            .addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
    },
    weekends:['01.01.2014','02.01.2014','03.01.2014','04.01.2014','05.01.2014','06.01.2014'],
    timepicker:false
});
var dateToDisable = new Date();
    dateToDisable.setDate(dateToDisable.getDate() + 2);
$('#datetimepicker11').datetimepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (date.getMonth() == dateToDisable.getMonth() && date.getDate() == dateToDisable.getDate()) {
            return [false, ""]
        }

        return [true, ""];
    }
});
$('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (date.getMonth() == dateToDisable.getMonth() && date.getDate() == dateToDisable.getDate()) {
            return [true, "custom-date-style"];
        }

        return [true, ""];
    }
});
$('#datetimepicker_dark').datetimepicker({theme:'dark'})


</script>
```

jquery dialogue box:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#wrapper').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Basic Dialog'
                });
                $('#opener').click(function() {
                    $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
//                  return false;
                });
            });
        </script>


<button id="opener">Open the dialog</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Some txt goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you have included jquery js twice `jquery.js` and `code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js`. Please include one of them at the top and see what you get.

Comment: yes you are right i have removed jquery.js and include code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js at top and it worked. thanks alot put your comment as answer so that i accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included jquery js twice `jquery.js` and `code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js`. Please include one of them at the top and see what you get.